# ORA-00979 Error

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, ora-00979

I am using oracle sql and was having issues with the group by function. I've been reading similar questions about this issue but have been unable to solve my problem.  For my problem, I have two tables [recruits (9), drill instructors(3)] and need to count the number of recruits (rid) for each drill instructor and display the drill instructors' f_name and l_name

I've tried a lot of variations of group by and order by.  This was the last formula I used:

```
Select di.f_name, di.l_name, count(recruits.rid) 
from di, recruits 
where di.di_id=recruits.di_id 
group by recruits.rid;
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Select di.f_name, di.l_name, count(recruits.rid) 
from di, recruits 
where di.di_id=recruits.di_id 
group by di.f_name, di.l_name
```

Also, you can use the more current join syntax

```
Select di.f_name, di.l_name, count(recruits.rid) 
from di
join recruits on di.di_id=recruits.di_id 
group by di.f_name, di.l_name
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much.  I realized that my error was that I wasn't including my di.f_name and di.l_name in the group by function since I was using it in my selection criteria.